# How to play only a part from a video with VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

I want to play a movie file from the commandline but not from start to end. Is it possible to use command line options that say "start the video from 0:05:17" and "stop the video on "00:49:32"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This worked with mine (Windows 7, VLC 1.1.11):

```
start "C:\Program Files\VLC\vlc.exe" "D:\Movies\The Italian Job.avi" --start-time 12 --stop-time 20
```

Just replace the file paths & seconds accordingly. The number `12` means the movie will start playing at the 12th second; the `20` means it'll stop at the 20th second.

Comment: On my Win7 with VLC 2.2.6 (Umbrella), I created a shortcut to the .avi file. In the shortcut, it wouldn't let me use "start" at the beginning. Rest of it worked like charm.Thanks a lot! :)